# How to detect scrollend of webview in android?

Tags: android, webview

Mine is a native app where I want to show/ hide a button if the user scrolls to the end of webview. I looked at an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956443/android-making-a-button-visible-once-webview-is-done-scrolling?lq=1) and got the entire idea of how to register the callback via interface. My major issue is that I am not able to get my calculations right inside the onScrollChanged method. I have tried combination of things like getHeight(), getContentHeight(), top etc but it just seems to fire too early. I tried with a simple page like google's with comparatively lesser content as well as a news page.

These logics work fine for a normal scroll view. Since the webpage has a lot of content, it could be messing up the calculations. Pasting a sample code: does not work.

```
@Override
protected void onScrollChanged(int left, int top, int oldLeft, int oldTop) {
    if ( mOnWebViewBottomReachedListener != null ) {
        //if ( (getContentHeight() - (top + getHeight())) <= mMinDistance )
        int diff = (getBottom() - (getHeight() + getScrollY()));
        Log.e("values ", diff+" o");
        if ((int) Math.floor(getContentHeight() * getScaleY()) == top)
            mOnWebViewBottomReachedListener.onBottomReached(this);
    }
    super.onScrollChanged(left, top, oldLeft, oldTop);
}
```

Need help with this. Thanks.

Comment: dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20513141/weird-miscalculation-when-trying-to-detect-if-webview-scrolled-to-bottom ?

Answer (score 17):

```
@Override
protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
    int height = (int) Math.floor(this.getContentHeight() * this.getScale());  
    int webViewHeight = this.getMeasuredHeight();  
    if(this.getScrollY() + webViewHeight >= height){  
       Log.i("THE END", "reached");
    }
    super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
}
```

This logic works fine for a webview.

Comment: nice try. but not works perfect because web view gives getContentHeight() of older web page when new page just loaded.

Comment: Just changed this.getScale() by newScale & get newScale in onScaleChanged method.Check more detail in https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onScaleChanged(android.webkit.WebView,%20float,%20float)

Comment: Worked for me when I changed getScale()(deprecated) to getScaleY(). I was trying to detect scroll to bottom.

Answer (score 13):

After a lot of google search all the solutions I found were calculating the height and determining the scrollOfset, but most of them are not reliable in most cases resulting in issues like described here [Weird miscalculation when trying to detect if WebView scrolled to bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20513141/weird-miscalculation-when-trying-to-detect-if-webview-scrolled-to-bottom)

I have found the solution that works 100% is to determine it based on overScroll

```
webView.setOnOverScrolledCallback(new WebViewCustom.OnOverScrolledCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onOverScrolled(int scrollX, int scrollY, boolean clampedX, boolean clampedY) {
                    if(clampedY)
                        if(scrollY == 0) {
                            //top
                        }
                        else {
                            //bottom
                        }

                }
            });
```

Comment: Nice method. Thank you.  I think, It will be useful for Android newbies to see a more detailed code fragment. Just add some note, e.g. WebView component should be extended by setOnOverScrolledCallback like it is demonstrated here http://qaru.site/questions/15337126/webview-in-nestedscrollview-scrolling

Comment: This worked for me after searching through a lot of comments in stackoverflow. thanks!

Comment: It's only available in API 23 and higher.

Comment: it works only API 23 and above

Answer (score 4):

Firstly extend your webview from this class. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14753235/3027225
After this upgrade your webView like this

```
 <com.YourPackageName.ObservableWebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```

And finally override the onScroll method like the following:

```
webView.setOnScrollChangedCallback(new OnScrollChangedCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onScroll(int l, int t) {
                  int tek = (int) Math.floor(webView.getContentHeight() * webView.getScale());
                  if(tek - webView.getScrollY() == webView.getHeight())
                     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "End", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

**This three method combination work excellent for me**

> 1. Create two boolean variable two detect topReached or bottomReached.
> 2. use computeVerticalScrollRange() to get vertical scroll range.
>      computeVerticalScrollRange() will help you when content height is less(In such case onScrollChanged not called).
> 3. use onScrollChanged to detect scrolling is happing.
>      **scrolling is happing** means content height is greater than webView measured height.Now detect bottom end using newt or detect top using newt.

```
private boolean topReached = false, bottomReached = false;

 @Override
protected int computeVerticalScrollRange() {

    int readerViewHeight = getMeasuredHeight();

    int verticalScrollRange = super.computeVerticalScrollRange();


    if (readerViewHeight >= verticalScrollRange) {

        topReached = true;

        bottomReached = true;

    }

    return verticalScrollRange;
}

@Override
protected void onScrollChanged(int newLeft, int newTop, int oldLeft, int oldTop) {

    Logger.i(TAG, "onScrollChanged");

    topReached = false;

    bottomReached = false;

    Log.i(TAG, "onScrollChanged newLeft : " + newLeft);
    Log.i(TAG, "onScrollChanged newTop : " + newTop);
    Log.i(TAG, "onScrollChanged oldLeft : " + oldLeft);
    Log.i(TAG, "onScrollChanged oldTop : " + oldTop);

    int readerViewHeight = getMeasuredHeight();

    int contentHeight = getContentHeight();

    if (newTop == 0) {

        Log.d(TAG, "onScrollChanged : Top End");

        topReached = true;

    } else if (newTop + readerViewHeight >= contentHeight) {

        Log.d(TAG, "onScrollChanged : Bottom End");

        bottomReached = true;

    }

    super.onScrollChanged(newLeft, newTop, oldLeft, oldTop);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Checked this on android version 8-11. it works 100%. I have achieved it by using `computeVerticalScrollRange` & `computeVerticalScrollExtent`.Following is an example of webview inside an activity/fragment.

Create a custom webview class.

```
public class MyWebView extends WebView {
    public MyWebView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyWebView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public int computeVerticalScrollRange() {
        return super.computeVerticalScrollRange();
    }

    @Override
    protected int computeVerticalScrollExtent() {
        return super.computeVerticalScrollExtent();
    }
}
```

In your layout file , implement webview like this and include this layout file into your `activity` or `fragment` view file if you need to.

```
 <in.package.folder.MyWebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"/>
```

In your activity/Fragment where you want to have the webview

1. declare variable

```
private MyWebView webView;
```

2. find the element id and initialize the webView

```
 webView = (MyWebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

3. Use `computeVerticalScrollRange` & `computeVerticalScrollExtent` methods defined in the `webview` class to calculate the end of scroll. 3rd parameter i1 ( Scroll Y) will be equal to (`computeVerticalScrollRange` - `computeVerticalScrollExtent`) if the scroll has reached the end of the webview content

```
 webView.setOnScrollChangeListener((view, i, i1, i2, i3) -> {
            int r1 = webView.computeVerticalScrollRange();
            int r2 = webView.computeVerticalScrollExtent();
            if (i1 == (r1 - r2)) {
                "REACHED END OF THE SCROLL"
            } 
        });
```

Comment: webView.computerVerticalScrollExtent() value never changes while scrolling . I tried the scrollY (i.e., i1 in your code) in place of webView.computeVerticalScrollExtent() and it worked fine .

Answer (score 2):

May a bit late to the party:

```
    enum class ScrollDirection(val direction: Int) {
        Upwards(-1),
        Downwards(1)
    }
        
     private fun detectOnScrollMaxDown() = with(binding) {
            webView.setOnScrollChangeListener { _, _, _, _, _ ->
                val isDownDirectPossible = webView.canScrollVertically(ScrollDirection.Downwards.direction)
                if (!isDownDirectPossible) Log.d("Reached the bottom? ","${!isDownDirectPossible}")
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following Kotlin codes work for me:

```
    web_view.setOnScrollChangeListener { v, scrollX, scrollY, oldScrollX, oldScrollY ->
        val measuredHeight: Int = web_view.measuredHeight
        if(measuredHeight + scrollY == web_view.computeVerticalScrollRange()){
            Log.d("WebView","Reach bottom")
        }
    }
```

Tested for Android 12 & Android 10. API level 31.

Comment: computeVerticalScrollRange() is protected

Comment: Please check Ole Pannier and Sachin Velaga answer.  Need to create a new class extend WebView.