# Detect End of scroll position custom webView

Tags: android, webview, onscrolllistener, onscrollchanged

I used a custom webView to make scroll listener for webView. 
and I want to use it like:

```
_webView = (ObservableWebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    _webView.setOnScrollChangedCallback(new ObservableWebView.OnScrollChangedCallback() {
        public void onScroll(int x, int y,int oldx,int oldy) {

             //if(end of scroll )
             //  { 
             //    log somthing
             //  }
        }
```

How can I to detect the end of scroll in it?Here is my ObservableWebView  class: [ObservableWebView class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14752523/how-to-make-a-scroll-listener-for-webview-in-android)

Comment: see this post it may be useful:[enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20998108/how-to-detect-scrollend-of-webview-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20998108/how-to-detect-scrollend-of-webview-in-android) post it may be useful

you can also use
     setOnScrollChange method event for api23