# How to detect end of webpage using OnTouchListener in android?

Tags: android

How to find the end of webpage using `WebView` ?

Following is my code :

```
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        webscroallposition = webView.getScrollY();

        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22005695/7461132).

Comment: i know but this works only after API 23, what should i do below 23 ?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but what about this? (Available for APIs < 23)

```
webView.setOnTouchListener { _, _ ->
    if (webView.canScrollVertically(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)) {
        // If the screen can scroll down
    } else {
        // If it can't
    }
    false
}
```