# Open multiple links in external browser

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I have a list of web urls. I need to open them all at once in an external browser where each link's page results in a new tab. So for example, if the list has a link to google.com and yahoo.com they should both be opened in the browser in their own separate tabs.

To open a single link within an external browser is pretty straight forward - create an ACTION_VIEW intent, set the url and call startActivity. But how can I do this with multiple urls? Doing multiple startActivity calls won't work. Any ideas?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Have you tried sending multiple URLs in a single intent?

Comment: How would you do that? Also, it should be browser-independent.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is based on a little research so I am not sure about the exact code but I will suggest an approach here

First you can have a `Fragment` or `Activity` with the `WebView` view type in the layout file respectively and depending on your use case, get the reference for the `WebView`. We will pass your list of urls to the activity containing the Webview

Say, we do it like so

```
val arrayList = getIntent().getArrayListExtra("urls")
val webView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.myWebview)
```

Now we can listen to scroll changes of the `WebView` and wait for the user to reach the end of the `WebView` page as given in the following link

[How to check the scrollend of WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20998108/how-to-detect-scrollend-of-webview-in-android)

And then when the scroll end is reached, we can load the next url from the array

```
webView.setOnScrollChangeListener((view, i, i1, i2, i3) -> {
            int r1 = webView.computeVerticalScrollRange();
            int r2 = webView.computeVerticalScrollExtent();
            if (i1 == (r1 - r2)) {
                webView.loadUrl(arrayList.get(1) // Or Whatever your next 
                index is
             // Maybe maintain a global variable for which url is currently 
            loaded
            } 
        });
```

To make the experience nice for the user you can consider setting a `WebViewClient` for your `WebView` and override `onProgressChanged` to show the progress to the user, just in case he doesn't feel lost

Comment: Let me know, if this works for you, I just had an idea in my head and then worked out a solution through some research for you

Comment: "in an external browser" seems to imply that the OP isn't using a WebView

Comment: @Code-Apprentice you're right, but I don't think of anyway by which we can have some control over the external browsers other than just requesting them to open url. So a `WebView` will always be preferred to have the functionality of the browser as well as customisation

Comment: Yes, that's right, there is no webview. They should be opened in the default browser, so the solution must be simple and general so it works in many browsers.

Comment: Alright so should I delete this answer then?